# Recursively Copy Files with Batch Script Without Using Xcopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

I need to recursively copy a set of files using a batch (DOS) script, maintaining the original directory structure. Sounds easy, right? Here are the complications:

1. xcopy is not available on the server I will be using the batch script on. Therefore, I have to use the copy command.
2. A thorough Internet search of this topic only leads to the use of xcopy, or some specialized use of the script (this is just a generic copy/paste job).
3. I have not written in DOS since the 90's.

How do I get the copy command to save to a new directory with the same name/location as the old one?

Comment: *robocopy* ships with some versions of Windows and is like xcopy on steroids.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using that does not have XCOPY? I thought all versions of Windows had XCOPY. Are you sure that your PATH is set appropriately to include the system folder where external commands reside?

Comment: Server 2008, but it's been really stripped down and probably misconfigured. Just another challenge heaped on my already full plate!

Comment: I suggest you to see: [recursively-find-and-replace-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422433/recursively-find-and-replace-files/10423757#10423757)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't copy `xcopy.exe` from a normal server?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested. The code supposedly duplicate the folder structure, but not copy files. If the test seems to be correct, remove the `ECHO` part from the `copy` command. The first parameter is "sourceDir" and the second one is "targetDir".

**EDIT**: Small detail fixed

```
@echo off
if not exist %2 md %2
set targetDir=%~F2
cd %1
call :processFolder
goto :EOF

:processFolder
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem For each folder in this level
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   rem Enter into it, process it and go back to original
   cd %%a
   set "targetDir=%targetDir%\%%a"
   if not exist "!targetDir!" md "!targetDir!"
   ECHO copy *.* "!targetDir!"
   call :processFolder
   cd ..
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "exitCode=0"

    set "sourceDir=%~1"
    set "targetDir=%~2"

    if not defined sourceDir (
        call :usage
        goto endProcess
    )
    if not defined targetDir (
        call :usage
        goto endProcess
    )

    for %%f in ("%sourceDir%") do set "sourceDir=%%~ff"
    for %%f in ("%targetDir%") do set "targetDir=%%~ff"

    if not exist "%sourceDir%" (
        call :error "Source directory does not exist"
        goto endProcess
    )
    if /i "%sourceDir%"=="%targetDir%" (
        call :error "Source and target are the same"
        goto endProcess
    )

    ver > nul
    call :recursiveFileCopy "%sourceDir%" "%targetDir%"
    if errorlevel 1 set "exitCode=1"

    goto endProcess

:recursiveFileCopy sourceDir targetDir  
    setlocal
    set "sourceDir=%~f1"
    set "targetDir=%~f2"
    if not exist "%targetDir%\" md "%targetDir%" || call :error "Failed to create [%targetDir%]"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        dir /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" >nul 2>nul && copy /y "%sourcedir%\*" "%targetdir%"
        pushd "%sourcedir%"
        for /d %%d in (*) do if not errorlevel 1 call :recursiveFileCopy "%%~fd" "%targetDir%\%%~nxd"
        popd
    )
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:usage
    echo(
    echo( Usage: %~n0 sourceDir targetDir
    echo(
:error
    echo(%~1
    set "exitCode=1" & cmd /d /q /c exit /b 1
    goto :eof

:endProcess
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```